# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42601]:

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.4, php-5.6

I am new to postgresql/postgis and am unable to solve this problem. I have lat long values which I retrieve by the click event and split using

```
lonlat.split(",");
```

But when I pass them into the following query, I receive a syntax error.

```
$sql1=$conn->prepare("select id,ST_Contains(geom,GeomFromText(4326,'POINT(".$lon." ".$lat.")')) as yes_within from public.".$layername);    
$sql1->execute();
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at end of input LINE 1: ...om,GeomFromText('POINT( )',4326)) as yes_within from public. ^' in C:\xampp\htdocs... Stack trace: #0  PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 22

Answer (score 0):

From the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at end of input LINE 1: ...om,GeomFromText('**POINT( )**',4326)) as yes_within from public. ^' in C:\xampp\htdocs... Stack trace: #0 PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 22

That means that even though you think you're getting them from split, you're not getting them from split. You're concatenating an empty string. The problem isn't in PostgreSQL.

Aside from that, don't construct a point that way. Instead use,

```
ST_MakePoint(long,lat)::geography
```

Which creates a `geography` not a `geometry` and it does it without text-parsing.

Comment: Thanks, I had used ST_MakePoint which had worked. But ST_Contains(geom,MakePoint($lon,$lat)) as yes_within always returns a false value. This means that the lat lon I am retrieving are never lying within the geom or maybe the layer i overlayed(using geoserver) over the base layer, is not attached to the layer beneath it so I am unable to retrieve anything from the database. Am I doing it in wrong way?